# Exporting 'mysql Client' module causes ReferencesError

Tags: module, referenceerror, deno

So I'm working with Deno on creating a framework for personal projects. The framework has been playing nice until I import the `Client` class from `https://deno.land/x/mysql@v2.9.0/mod.ts` to work with MySQL

If I add

`export { Client } from 'https://deno.land/x/mysql@v2.9.0/mod.ts';`

I get the following error in an independent area of my app

```
Check file:///Users/USER/Workspace/project/lib/cli.ts
error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'RequestMiddleware' before initialization
    request: RequestMiddleware
```

If I change the export to anything else aka

`export { spy as Client } from 'https://deno.land/x/mock@v0.9.5/mod.ts';`

or

`export class Client {}`

Then no error occurs

Comment: Can you share the relevant code from `lib/cli.ts` where the Client class is used? Right now I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I've fixed it, not entirely sure what was causing the issue but the I moved the export of the `RequestMiddleware` to another file and changed the import to match it and it worked. Not sure why importing that specific module caused it to happen though.